# Keep image aspect ratio and inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to have an image inside a div (the violet one, see images below), whose dimensions are expressed in %, and that the image never go out from the div but resize when needed, keeping the aspect ratio.

Currently, my code is the following but the image comes out from the div as you can see in the pictures below.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#grille {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

#colonne {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

#cellule {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  background-color: aqua;
}

#conteneurImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: violet;
}

#conteneurImage img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="grille">
    <div id="colonne">
      <div id="cellule">
        <div id="conteneurImage">
          <img src="home.png">
        </div>
        <div id="conteneurTexte">
          Accueil
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>
```

The result:

[image: the result]

What I expect:

[image: what I expect]

Comment: use object-fit property

Comment: Just use `max-height: 100%` and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "display: flex; justify-content: center; " in #conteneurImage. And then Use "width:auto;height:100%;" in #conteneurImage img.You can learn more about flex in https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#grille {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

#colonne {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

#cellule {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  background-color: aqua;
}

#conteneurImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: violet;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#conteneurImage img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="grille">
    <div id="colonne">
      <div id="cellule">
        <div id="conteneurImage">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2/2144.svg">
        </div>
        <div id="conteneurTexte">
          Accueil
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>
```